# My React app showing a blank page on my localhost

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I am using VSCode to create a react app, I have multiple folders as shown in the first image:

[image]

This is my App.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import Note from "./components/Note";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Footer />
      <Note />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is my Index.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.document.getElementById("root"));

reportWebVitals();
```

This is my Header.jsx

```
import React from "react";

function Header() {
  return (
    <header>
      <h1>Keeper</h1>
    </header>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

This is my Footer.jsx

```
import React from "react";

function Footer() {
  const date = new Date();
  const curretYear = date.getFullYear();
  return (
    <footer>
      <p>copyright ⓒ {curretYear}</p>;
    </footer>
  );
}

export default Footer;
```

I am trying to learn react on VSCode, the same code works on Codesandbox, but I can't get it to work on my VSCode, and I am not getting any errors in the terminal. I am learning React and I would like the help.

Comment: Show your index.html file. It should be calling to your index.js inside a div with id = root

Comment: Why `document.document.getElementById`?  Why the double `document.` ?  That seems wrong.  Is that just a typo?  I would have expected a `Cannot read properties of undefined` error trying to access `.GetElementById` of `document.document` which is probably undefined.  So are you actually running the code you think you are?  Did it fail to build and then you are running a stale version or something?  There's something fishy here.

Comment: If the same code works in a codesandbox, maybe you could provide the link to the working version too.

Comment: Please either mark the answer that best answered your question as the correct answer or specify what is missing from the answers so that we can find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your import paths in App.jsx appear to be wrong try ./Header etc. Remember that import paths are relative and since the imported modules are on the same level as App.jsx, you don't need to go through the components folder